# Write matlab data from gui to excel file and read only file

Tags: excel, matlab, user-interface

I have a Matlab GUI that I generate values in and send to the workspace with the assignin() command.

I need to be able to send the data that I generate to a read only file in excel. I also want the user to be able to name the file. I haven't been able to do this with either the xlswrite command or the save command.

Thank you for your time in advance here is the code that I have been trying to use.

```
function save_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to save (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
state=get(hObject, 'Value');
if state==1
global stop_state;
stop_state = 0;
pause(1);
prompt = 'What is the file name you want to save to';
filename = input(prompt,'s');
new_file = strcat(filename,'.xlsx');
xlswrite(new_file,y(idx));
end
```

I have been getting the error that the variables don't exist that i am sending over even though i can see  their name in the workspace.

Comment: the read only file doesn't need to be excel it can be CSV, PDF, .txt etc

Comment: Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38852015/edit) to show the exact error and which line gives it?  I am guessing the error says that neither `y` nor `idx` exists.  I think you will probably have more luck storing in the userdata rather than using `assignin`, since then you can get the userdata from `handles` and pass it to `xlswrite`.

Comment: i figured out the error and am now writing a table to excel i just need to figure out how to make the file read only instead of a normal .xlsx file

Comment: it doesnt necessarily need to be read only just a non editable file

Comment: you mean you want it read only (by OS) after you wrote your data in it?

Comment: no read only by users after it's been published so a copy that cant be edited by users